# How do I install a .dtx file?

Tags: installing, dtx

When I run:

```
tex algorithms.dtx
```

for example, I get this message.

```
  ! Undefined control sequence.
l.34 \documentclass
                   {ltxdoc}
?
```

Help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on how the `.dtx` is constructed, it may not work at all with TeX: you have to use (pdf)latex. To unpack the file you may well need an `.ins` file.

Comment: @an_ant: it doesn't need to be deleted, because it might help other users. You could even improve that chance if you change the title to "Installing a dtx file" or similar, so it could be found by users with a similar problem but any arbitrary package.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: Got it. I'll try to manage it.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot that you should "Run LaTeX on the .ins file to unpack the .dtx file".

Comment: Could this answer contain something like "run (pdf)latex on the `.ins` file", so that it's more clear to others with the question (How do I install a .dtx file?)

Answer (score 20):

I was having difficulty to understand the accepted answer. It's not the fault of the answer, just that the accepted answer was not targeted to novice (like me). So here is what I figured that I need to run to get the sty file from a dtx:

`tex algorithms.dtx`

I ran this for `pullquote`, and got the following response (and the required .sty file):

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=tex)
(./pullquote.dtx
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/docstrip.tex
Utility: `docstrip' 2.5e <2014/09/29>
English documentation    <2017/03/13>

**********************************************************
* This program converts documented macro-files into fast *
* loadable files by stripping off (nearly) all comments! *
**********************************************************

********************************************************
* No Configuration file found, using default settings. *
********************************************************

)

Generating file(s) pullquote.sty

Processing file pullquote.dtx (package) -> pullquote.sty
File pullquote.dtx ended by \endinput.
Lines  processed: 2209
Comments removed: 1500
Comments  passed: 0
Codelines passed: 692


Generating file(s) pullquote.ins

Processing file pullquote.dtx (install) -> pullquote.ins
File pullquote.dtx ended by \endinput.
Lines  processed: 2209
Comments removed: 1500
Comments  passed: 0
Codelines passed: 692


Generating file(s) README.txt

Processing file pullquote.dtx (readme) -> README.txt
File pullquote.dtx ended by \endinput.
Lines  processed: 2209
Comments removed: 1500
Comments  passed: 0
Codelines passed: 692

Overall statistics:
Files  processed: 3
Lines  processed: 6627
Comments removed: 4500
Comments  passed: 0
Codelines passed: 2076
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on pullquote.log.
```

(This should really be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that)

Answer (score 9):

Joseph Wright says "run `latex` on the `.ins`"; however, if you have LaTeX, you also have `ltxdoc.cls`, etc., so that unpacking the `.dtx` doesn't help.

Processing the `.dtx` file with `(pdf)latex` gives all you need -- a file of documentation.

Comment: "gives all you need -- a file of documentation" But I don't want the documentation: I was the cls or sty file. How are those generated?

Answer (score 7):

You may need an `.sty` file, which can be extracted from a `.dtx` by doing the following:

- Go to the folder where the `.dtx` file is located
- Run `tex file_name.dtx`

This should generate some other files on the current directory, one of which is a `.sty` file.

Then, move the `file_name.sty` directly into your project folder, where a file will use it, or somewhere where latex will look for lib files ([check this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) for info on that).

Comment: There is a list of the places to put extracted files at http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/pkginst.html#rightplace (create your own Personal TeX Directory first — see http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/personal.html)