# Installing packages (that don't include a .sty file) with BSD

Tags: packages, installing

I've recently switched to DragonFlyBSD on my laptop, and I've been having trouble getting LaTeX to function properly. I've installed teTeX and can compile simple .tex files fine, but I cannot find a package manager to install missing packages on-the-fly. As a result, I've resorted to installing them manually. This is alright with me (I use relatively few packages, so it's not a major inconvenience), but it doesn't always work. When teTeX runs across a missing package, it asks for the location of the associated .sty file. But not all packages come with a .sty file, for example ifmtarg. What am I supposed to do in this case?

Also, if there is a good package manager for DragonFlyBSD, I'm all ears. It appears that TeX Live does not work with DragonFlyBSD, which is the only program with a package manager that's supposed to work on any BSD install.

Comment: Unpacking code for LaTeX packages is not OS-dependent: we've had for example [How do I install a .dtx file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6925) in the past. On the DragonFlyBSD point, TeX Live covers any OS that there are builds available for: the problem is finding volunteers for each one. FreeBSD is currently covered, and OpenBSD used to be but I think the person doing that dropped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I simply need to compile the provided files using pdflatex in order to produce the .sty files. This solves the issue.