# Using APA6 Package Returns Cannont Find apa6.sty Error

Tags: errors, apa6

### The Problem

When attempting to use the APA6 package, I received this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `apa6.sty' not found.
```

And a little later, I see the following warnings:

```
Class apa6 Warning: Short title not defined.
Class apa6 Warning: Affiliation not defined.
Class apa6 Warning: Abstract not defined.
```

Fairly self-explanatory, or so I thought...

### What I've Tried

I've reviewd the following, including the comments, and none of the provided ideas/solutions have worked:

[Installing packages (that don't include a .sty file) with BSD](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88795/90612)

[How do I install a .dtx file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6925/90612)

[tracklang.sty missing in miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220924/90612)

I have already tried using the package manager to uninstall and reinstall the apa6 package. Additionally, I have also attempted installing the package manually. But upon processing the files, no .sty file is produced, using either `latex` or `pdflatex`.

### Additional Info and MCVE

I am using MiKTeX 2.9, on a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional machine, and the only other interesting thing that I've noted was that the value of `TEXMFMAIN` does not correspond to a path that actually exists on my system:

```
ß kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFMAIN
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9
```

I am thinking that could be the issue, but I have yet to locate any information on how to affect that variable's value.

MCVE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{apa6}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\title{My Title}
\date{}
\author{My name}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{center}\section{Section 1}\end{center}

    \subsection{subsection}
        \paragraph{para title} paragraph 1\textsuperscript{\cite{ref1}}.

    \begin{center}\section{Section 2}\end{center}

    \subsection{subsection}
        \paragraph{para title} paragraph 2\textsuperscript{\cite{ref2}}.

    \flushleft
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
        \bibitem{ref1}

        \bibitem{ref2}

        \bibitem{ref3}
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

% % % % % % Sources to add to References
%
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
```

Is the apa6 package supposed to have a sty file and, if so, how can I go about getting a hold of a copy of it?

Comment: There is no `apa6.sty`, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apa6` bundle contains no `apa6.sty` file. Here's the output of `tlmgr info apa6 --list` (without the description part):

```
run files:
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/apa6.cls
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAamerican.txt
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAbritish.txt
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAczech.txt
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAdutch.txt
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAendfloat.cfg
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAenglish.txt
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAgerman.txt
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAgreek.txt
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAngerman.txt
source files:
  texmf-dist/source/latex/apa6/apa6.dtx
  texmf-dist/source/latex/apa6/apa6.ins
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/README details="Readme"
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/apa6.pdf details="Package documentation"
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/pseudoTeX/TeX2WordForapa6.bas
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/pseudoTeX/apa6.ptex
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/samples/Figure1.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/samples/bibliography.bib
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/samples/longsample.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/samples/shortsample.tex
```

It's no different for MiKTeX, that uses the same. If we look at the `apa6.ins` file that's used to build the runtime files, we see

```
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.cls}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{class}}
}
\usedir{tex/latex/apa6/config}
\generate{
  \file{./config/APAamerican.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{american}}
  \file{./config/APAbritish.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{british}}
  \file{./config/APAdutch.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{dutch}}
  \file{./config/APAenglish.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{english}}
  \file{./config/APAgerman.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{german}}
  \file{./config/APAngerman.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{ngerman}}
  \file{./config/APAgreek.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{greek}}
  \file{./config/APAczech.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{czech}}
  \file{./config/APAendfloat.cfg}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{APAendfloat}}
}
\usedir{tex/latex/apa6/samples}
\generate{
  \file{./samples/bibliography.bib}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{bibliography}}
  \file{./samples/shortsample.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{shortsample}}
  \file{./samples/longsample.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{longsample}}
}
\usedir{tex/latex/apa6/pseudoTeX}
\generate{
  \file{./pseudoTeX/apa6.ptex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{ptex}}
  \file{./pseudoTeX/TeX2WordForapa6.bas}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{bas}}
}
```

and again there is no trace of `apa6.sty`.

Remove `\usepackage{apa6}`, because it's wrong.

---

In order to get rid of the warnings, define the required parts as in the following example. Note that you are *not* supposed to add `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` around section titles, that are centered by default.

Also `\flushleft` before `\begin{thebibliography}` is wrong. Maybe `\raggedright` after it, if you want ragged right typesetting.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\title{My Title}
\shorttitle{My Title}
\date{}
\author{My name}
\affiliation{My university}

\begin{document}

\abstract{An abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{subsection}

\paragraph{para title} paragraph 1\textsuperscript{\cite{ref1}}.

\section{Section 2}

\subsection{subsection}

\paragraph{para title} paragraph 2\textsuperscript{\cite{ref2}}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{ref1} Some item

\bibitem{ref2} Some item

\bibitem{ref3} Some item

\bibitem{ref4} Some item

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well. That would be my problem right there. FNGs I tell  ya. Thanks egreg!

Comment: @nihilon I added some recommendations