# Compiling .dtx file to .sty

Tags: packages, installing, dtx

I downloaded the [`fancytooltips`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancytooltips) package, including the files `fancytooltips.dtx` and `fancytooltips.ins`, and then compiling three times with `pdflatex fancytooltips.dtx`. I see that the user guide `fancytooltips.pdf` shows up, but no `.sty` file appears, which I thought it should. Am I missing something?

Comment: have a look at [How do I install a .dtx file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6927/15717)

Comment: There should also be a `.ins` file. Run this file.

Comment: BTW, both TeX Live and MiKTeX do know a distribution package `fancytooltips`, thus there is no need for manual installation.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, I've already gotten the package via TexLive. I was just trying manual installation in case I will play around with the package a little bit. Thanks!