# Latex: How to generate derived .sty files?

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to compile a template which uses the "todonotes" package, which I have found here:
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/?lang=en

When I run latex on the template I get the following message printed to terminal:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `todonotes.sty' not found.
```

I realize that I need to include the .sty file in the directory from which I compile. However the .sty is not available for download from anywhere that I can find. The files todonotes.dtx and todonotes.ins are available for download on the quoted CTAN page.

How do I get the todonotes.sty file? Do I need to somehow generate it from the .dtx and .ins files?

Comment: Welcome! Don't download it manually. Use your TeX distribution's package manager to install the package. Both MikTeX and TeX Live provide package managers and this package is part of standard TeX distributions. I'm guessing you are either using MikTeX or a Linux distro's TeX Live packages. In the second case, you should find out which package your distro includes `todonotes.sty` in. This will depend on your distro. (Or consider the easier option of ditching your distro's TeX Live packages and installing vanilla from upstream ;).)

Comment: See [How do I install a `.dtx` file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6925/5764)