# using the elsarticle template from Elsevier

Tags: miktex, elsarticle

I'm new to LaTeX. I just downloaded the elsarticle.zip folder from ctan.org but I don't understand how to use it. the zip folder has a .dtx, .ins, and .tex files. The documentation said to run the .ins file in my editor (I use miktex and texmaker), but when I did, it gave an error window saying 'couldn't start the command'. when I tried to compile the .tex file, I got a fatal error. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the ctan catalogue shows that elsarticle is already in miktex so you shouldn't need to get it from ctan and install by hand either you should have it already or the miktex package manager will get and install it for you.

Comment: A working example can be downloaded from www.elsevier.com/latex. The link is hidden in the second paragraph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .dtx file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/how-do-i-install-a-dtx-file)