# With R, knitr and RStudio, how do you compile a .dtx file to get the .sty file needed for a package?

Tags: r, knitr, dtx, pullquote

Working through Stefan Kottwitz's *LaTeX Cookbook*, page 82, I tried  to use the package `pullquote`.

I am using `R`, the `knitr` library and the RStudio IDE.  When I compiled the .Rnw script that has the page 83 code, the compile failed because "File 'pullquote.sty'not found"

The book helpfully tells where to find online the requisite .dtx file that will generate the missing `pullquote.sty`.  I copied that .dtx file into the directory where the .Rnw script is (the working directory), but that alone obviously will not succeed.

A few lines later the book says "Compile the `pullquote.dtx` file with `LaTeX`.

How can I do that within the `R`, `knitr`, RStudio setup?  Perhaps [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/how-do-i-install-a-dtx-file) should help me, but it doesn't because I don't know how to run `(pdf)latex`.  Or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/how-do-i-install-a-dtx-file) speaks of running `pdflatex` on the .dtx file, but how does one do that and and where do you save the result?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to run pdflatex in a terminal, ie., typing 'latex pullquote.dtx' into a terminal. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am on Windows 10.  In the command line I can do what you suggest, Christian, but how do I save the result (the .sty?) and do I save it where my other LaTeX packages are?

Comment: Have you just tried `pdflatex pullquote.dtx` from the terminal?

Comment: The resulting .sty file should be located in the folder you ran latex on the .dtx file. You can put it into the same folder as your .tex file. If you want to add it permanently and you are using MikTeX the following answer could be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/93559

Comment: From the console of RStudio:  > system("pdflatex pullquote.dtx")
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `pullquote.dtx'.
<*> pullquote.dtx